# Mootool on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile

1. Is Mootols compatible with mobile devices?
2. Is there an emulator where I can test a site developed with Mootools on a mobile device?
3. Is there a way, in JavaScript, to detect if the browser is a mobile one or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, providing that device has good JS support, which all Android, iOS and Blackberries do.
2. Yes. [Android one here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html). Google around for the iPhone/iPod one.
3. Yes. There is information [here](http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2010/10/how-to-detect-browser-using-mootools-1-3-javascript/), [here](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ipad) and [here](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-iphone).

Mootools has a [mobile addon](http://mootools.net/forge/p/mobile) which should help.